# Not able to install ffvideo

Tags: software-installation, pip

```
Downloading/unpacking ffvideo
  Downloading FFVideo-0.0.13.tar.gz (47kB): 47kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/doublespring/.virtualenvs/team/build/ffvideo/setup.py) egg_info for package ffvideo

Installing collected packages: ffvideo
  Running setup.py install for ffvideo
    building 'ffvideo' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/ffmpeg -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ffvideo/ffvideo.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ffvideo/ffvideo.o
    ffvideo/ffvideo.c:254:32: fatal error: libavutil/rational.h: No such file or directory
     #include "libavutil/rational.h"
                                    ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/doublespring/.virtualenvs/team/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/doublespring/.virtualenvs/team/build/ffvideo/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-baqEa_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/doublespring/.virtualenvs/team/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_ext

building 'ffvideo' extension

creating build

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ffvideo

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/ffmpeg -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ffvideo/ffvideo.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ffvideo/ffvideo.o

ffvideo/ffvideo.c:254:32: fatal error: libavutil/rational.h: No such file or directory

 #include "libavutil/rational.h"

                                ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 1):

The most probable issue (a part a possible bug in the package) is that you are missing some dependent package. Let's try to teach how to fish out these...

Install `apt-file`  and load its database

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Search for the missing file:

```
[romano:~] % apt-file search libavutil/rational.h
libavutil-dev: /usr/include/libavutil/rational.h
libmyth-dev: /usr/include/mythtv/libavutil/rational.h
```

That means that there are two packages providing a `libavutil/rational.h` file. The second one is part of `myth-tv` --- very specialized thing. So the most probable culprit for your error is missing the first one:

```
 sudo apt-get install libavutil-dev
```

...and try again.